# Angular 4 i18n example how to implement i18n in angular 4

Tags: angular

How to implement i18n in angular 4.I am new in angular 4 .I would like to implement `i18n` in angular 4 project . This angular 4 project is generated by angular `CLI` . Please help me how can i do it .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

This is so simple. Just do:

`npm install @ngx-translate/core @ngx-translate/http-loader --save`

Then you should create a folder in ~/src/assets with the name `i18n`

And import the `app.module.ts` module

```
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
```

Before of import all modules you need to add this:

```
// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

Then... in `@NgModule` IMPORTS

```
HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient]
          }
     })
```

And, to finish add the `translateService`

```
// ngx-translate
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';`
```

Declare in the constructor and then set the default language

```
 constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.addLangs(["en", "es"]);
        translate.setDefaultLang('en');

        let browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
        translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|es/) ? browserLang : 'en');
  }
```

After this is complete, you need create the files:

~/src/assets/es.json and ~/src/assets/en.json in my case with this format:

```
{
  "CARD": {
    "NAME": "Celiz Morante Matias Nahuel",
    "TITLE": "Full Stack JS Developer",
    "EMAIL": "mceliz@....it.com.ar",
    "PHONE": "+549....",
    "SKYPE": "enl...",
    "ADDRESS": "Jo.. Inge... ...40",
    "GITHUB": "https://github.com/G33N",
    "LINKEDIN": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/matias-nahuel-celiz-morante-994719149/"
  },
  "EXPERIENCE": {
    "TITLE": "Experience"
  },
  "EDUCATION": {
    "TITLE": "Education"
  },
  "PORTFOLIO": {
    "TITLE": "Portfolio"
  },
  "FOOTER": {

  }
}
```

And this is the way to call in the template:

```
<h2>{{ 'EXPERIENCE.TITLE' | translate }}</h2>
```

This was a resume of https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#installation

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you are looking for:
The internationalization (i18n) library for Angular 2+
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Comment: Thank you Bob, i will try this

Comment: Official Angular 4 documentation for i18n: 
 https://v4.angular.io/guide/i18n --- Official Angular 5 i18n documentation: https://angular.io/guide/i18n